# Shouldn't "takes one values" be "takes one value"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

A doubt assails me while reading [this paper](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs109/reader/4%20Random%20Variables.pdf).

> We can define events that occur if the random variable takes one
>   values that satisfy a numerical test.

I wonder if the above sentence is grammatical? I thought "one values" should be "one value". Or I am missing something? It is from a very popular course.

Comment: I think this is probably just a typo for "one of the values that ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a grammatical error, and likely an inadvertent one (aka, a "typo").  It looks like the author intended to say "...one of the values that satisfy...", but also had "...one value that satisfies..." in mind, and mixed up elements of the two sentences.  This kind of error is common among native speakers of English.